# How can I recover emails from twenty years ago on my yahoo sent box?

Tags: email, email-client, email-filter, yahoo-mail, yahoo-messenger

I have been using the same email address on yahoo all my life. I sent an email to someone in 2002 containing some vital informantion which I now need. When I consult the sent box and sort by displaying the older emails at the top, I only see two emails from 2002 and what I want is not among the two. These two are followed by emails from 2014. All emails I sent between 2002 and 2014 are not available. I will like to know if it's possible to recover them because it is very unlikely that I deleted them myself.  Thank you

Comment: Yahoo may have been automatically deleting old emails for you

Comment: I would think so except that there are 2 emails there from 2002 and none till 2014.

Comment: Are they really from 2002? (they might have been received later with a faked date in the past) They might also have been on a different folder, then moved back to inbox (with such deletion policy only applying to inbox)

Comment: Sounds like you might be out of luck.

Comment: They are in my sent box like I said. They give me the impression that I didn't send any email after that till 2014 which isn't true.